# Meteor/AWS: Twitter popup not closing when logging in

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, meteor, twitter, oauth

I am running a meteor application on a server on Amazon (AWS), which I think creates a problem.

The error is this: when I run `Meteor.loginWithTwitter()`, the pop-up for Twitter starts, asks for permission, I click okay, but then the process stops. I just see a blank window with a long URL but nothing happens. If I refresh the popup-window I get this error message:

> {"line":"398","file":"oauth_server.js","message":"Error in OAuth
>   Server: Unable to retrieve request token","time":
>   "$date":1465297660431},"level":"warn"}
>
> Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Unable to retrieve
>   request token
>
> ```
> at OAuth._requestHandlers.(anonymous function) (packages/oauth1/oauth1_server.js:61:1)
> at middleware (packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:173:1)
> at packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:146:1
> ```

I get this error both when I create a new project on the server or when I start the actual project I'm trying to get to work. The error message from when I run the actual project is the same as above, though it says it originates from a different place:

> ```
> at OAuth._requestHandlers.(anonymous function) (packages/oauth1.js:305:13)
> at middleware (packages/oauth.js:203:5)
> at packages/oauth.js:176:5
> ```

On Twitter I have these setting:

**Website:**

```
http://myapp.com
```

**Callback URL:**

```
http://myapp.com/_oauth/twitter?close
```

For my own envirment I have set the ROOT_URL to the same webpage as on twitter.

I have also tried to direct Twitter to the IP-adress, or to just myapp.com, or to have no callback URL at all (which of course shouldn't work, but I cannot understand why I keep getting this error).

[Someone suggested](https://forums.meteor.com/t/unable-to-retrieve-request-token-error/7042) to another who had a similar problem that one should make sure that one's server can receive signals. Earlier the security settings for my aws-server was that port 80 was open for any HTTP-traffic, and now I set it so All traffic, for all protocols and all ports are open from any source, without any change.

I'm guessing this problem shows up because I'm running the app on AWS - I didn't get this problem a few months ago when I ran it from my home. But I really have no idea why it happens, nor where to keep searching to find out.

Does anybody know why the problem appears, or a way to get around it?

Comment: I guess this is happening because of http you will have to use https.

Comment: I used http when I hosted the site from my own ip adress and that worked fine.

Comment: So you are saying it was working first and suddenly it stopped working?

Comment: No, it's like this: A few months back I was running the node server from my own home and had twitter use just my ip-adress as a callback. I didn't have any ssl-certificates then - I hadn't even bought my domain name - so it was just running from http:// x.xx.xx.xx but it was running fine. But now, when I run it from Amazon's web service, it doesn't work.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: I don't know, could have been some glitch with accounts-twitter because I used node v. 0.10.43, or with Twitter, or maybe Twitter has this problem with http for domain adresses (but not with just ip-adresses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error2007 suggested I should try to use a https-callback instead of just http, which proved to be spot on.

To get https running I

- got two certificates from Let's Encrypt with Certbot - one certificate for mypage.com and one for www.mypage.com (some other certificates, that costs money, will certify both without www).
- setup nginx to handle calls to port 80 and 443 and forward them to my meteor app. I followed the instructions in [How To Deploy a Meteor.js Application on Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx) entirely, except I followed [these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) instructions to get a Diffie-Hellman group and to not move the pem-keys and just changing nginx default file instead of creating symbolic links for a new one. I did the same for my picture server, that I can serve through https:// myapp.com:444.
- Also, to get both www.myapp and myapp to get through a https-connection I have two nginx-reroutes. On listens for www-calls and certifies with the www-certificate and the other waits for no-www-calls and certifies with the no www-calls - but they both go the same meteor localhost connection on the server.

It also worked fine to either have `/_oauth/twitter?close` at the end of the callback-URL on Twitter or not.